# Apache Ignite with Spring Boot CrudRepo cannot be initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I am trying to set up a small Ignite application using a IgniteCrudRepository.

Since the current stable version 2.6.0 has issues with spring data integration (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6879) I am using the latest nighty build of 2.7.0.

When I try to start the application it fails with the following exception:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize Ignite repository factory. Ignite instance or IgniteConfiguration or a path to Ignite's spring XML configuration must be defined in the application configuration
```

But in my spring boot application I do create an Ignite bean and in the debug logs I see that spring knows about that bean.

```
Eagerly caching bean 'ignite' to allow for resolving potential circular reference
```

My spring boot application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIgniteRepositories
@Configuration
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Ignite ignite(){

        IgniteConfiguration configuration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        configuration.setIgniteInstanceName("myApp");
        configuration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Page> cache = new CacheConfiguration<>("pageCache");
        cache.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Page.class);
        configuration.setCacheConfiguration(cache);

        return Ignition.start(configuration);
    }
}
```

The repo is defined like this:

```
import org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.IgniteRepository;


public interface PageRepository extends IgniteRepository<Page, Integer> {
}
```

And injecting the Ignite bean into my controller also works, confirmed that by debugging into it. Implementation is of type IgniteKernal.

So I do not get why the repository cannot be created as the required bean seems part of the application context. There is no additional xml or java configuration.

I know 2.7.0 is not released yet and this might be a bug in the nightly build. But maybe someone had this issue before or has an idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have to name the bean `igniteInstance`. See the last paragpraph [here](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-data#section-spring-data-and-apache-ignite-configuration). It says that you can either have `igniteInstance`, `igniteCfg` or `igniteSpringCfgPath`.

Comment: Indeed.. good catch. I was too hung up on the error message that suggested the classes did not match.. d'oh..

Comment: I have the same problem, but after resolving it, i have this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534260/apache-ignite-2-7-igniterepository-with-jpa2-is-not-injected. Do anybody know how to fix it?